# How to make an activity not reload/refresh every time I get into it?

Tags: java, android

I have an activity and I don't want it to reload every time I get into it. I want it to show the information which had the last time i got into it.
But I also want to have one Button in another activity that will refresh the other activity, so that when i get into it the information has changed. I say that the content changes because the activity show different recyclerviews everytime you get into it.

That is my MainActivity.java:

```java
public class Comida extends AppCompatActivity implements Adaptador2.OnRecipeListener {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView1;
    List<Entidad2> listItems;
    Adaptador2 adaptor;
    private Entidad2 entidad1,entidad2,entidad3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comida);

        recyclerView1 = findViewById(R.id.lv_1);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        entidad1 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.calabacines_3, "Solomillo a la plancha", " 10 min.", 4, 20);
        entidad2 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.patatas_deluxe_especiadas_70523_300_150, "Entrecot", " 15 min.", 2, 50);
        entidad3 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.tomate, "Hamburguesa", " 2 min.", 5, 100);


        listItems.add(entidad1);
        listItems.add(entidad2);
        listItems.add(entidad3);

        adaptor = new Adaptador2(listItems, this);
        recyclerView1.setAdapter(adaptor);
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
        pickEntidad();
    }
    @Override
    public void OnRecipe(int priority) {

        if (priority == 20) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Solomillo.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
        if (priority == 50) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Entrecot.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
        if (priority == 100) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Hamburguesa.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    }

    private void pickEntidad(){
        final int random = new Random().nextInt(101);

        int priority1 = entidad1.getPriority();
        int priority2 = entidad2.getPriority();
        int priority3 = entidad3.getPriority();


        listItems.clear();
        if(random < priority1){

            listItems.add(entidad1);

        }else if(random < priority2){

            listItems.add(entidad2);

        }else if (random <= priority3){

            listItems.add(entidad3);

        }
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And that is my activityWithButton.java:

```java
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button boton_start;
    Button boton_refresh;
    Button boton_prueba;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        boton_start=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_platos);
        boton_refresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_cambiarmenu);
        boton_prueba=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_menu);

        boton_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent in = new Intent(Menu.this,Dishes.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
        boton_prueba.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent in = new Intent(Menu.this,Comida.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
        boton_prueba.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //What to do?

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Please help I don't know what to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have two fairly straight-forward options, **SharedPreferences** and **SavedInstanceState**.

**SharedPreferences**, you can access and save data anywhere `context` is available within your app assigning a `key, value` pair to any data to later be retreived. Generally you will want to save the data during certain lifecycle events such as `onStop` and retreive it somewhere else once the activity returns:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    editor.putString("key", "My string");
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String myValue = editor.getString("key");
}
```

**SavedInstanceState**, comes with the `onCreate` override method in your activities. Utilising the available override method `onSaveInstanceState`, pass in the required data when the activity is temprarily destroyed to be retreived on its  recreation.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        String myValue = savedInstanceState.getString("key");
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
   outState.putString("key", "My string");
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Further reading https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: I've tried the second option but it says that myValue :cannot resolve symbol

Comment: It is calling ```savedInstanceState.getString()``` so myValue needs to be a string variable.

Comment: Thanks but none of the two methods worked to stop the reload any other idea?

Comment: They will work, everytime the activity reloads it is recreated and the data will start from new. This is how you save the previous data, and then check if any data is already saved before applying all the default data to each element on screen.

Comment: Please I'm confused, what do I exactly have to do? To use the first or the second method?

Comment: Before you set default data to your activity you can check to see if it has already been saved ```if (myValue  != null)```

Comment: I know that but still don't know which method i have to use

Comment: As far as I know, `SharedPreferences` is good to store data that should survive even after the app is closed from the recents menu by the user.
`SavedInstanceState` can restore data if an app was put to background and killed by the system (to free up some RAM for example).
So if you want the data to be restored even if the user closes the app in recents menu, go with `SharedPreferences`, if you only want to store data within one app session, `SharedPreferences` will be fine.