# How to make an activity not reload every time I get into it, and make a button reload it?

Tags: java, android

I have an activity and I don't want it to reload every time I get into it. I want it to show the information which had the last time I got into it.
But I also want to have one Button in another activity that will refresh the other activity, so that when I get into it the information has changed.
I say that the content changes because the activity shows different recyclerviews every time you get into it.

And that is my activityWithButton.java:

```java
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button boton_start;
    Button boton_refresh;
    Button boton_prueba;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        boton_start=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_platos);
        boton_refresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_cambiarmenu);
        boton_prueba=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_menu);

        boton_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent in = new Intent(Menu.this,Dishes.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
        boton_prueba.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent in = new Intent(Menu.this,Comida.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
        boton_prueba.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //What to do?

            }
        });

    }
}
```

That is my MainActivity.java:

```java
public class Comida extends AppCompatActivity implements Adaptador2.OnRecipeListener {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView1;
    List<Entidad2> listItems;
    Adaptador2 adaptor;
    private Entidad2 entidad1,entidad2,entidad3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comida);

        recyclerView1 = findViewById(R.id.lv_1);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        entidad1 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.calabacines_3, "Solomillo a la plancha", " 10 min.", 4, 20);
        entidad2 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.patatas_deluxe_especiadas_70523_300_150, "Entrecot", " 15 min.", 2, 50);
        entidad3 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.tomate, "Hamburguesa", " 2 min.", 5, 100);


        listItems.add(entidad1);
        listItems.add(entidad2);
        listItems.add(entidad3);

        adaptor = new Adaptador2(listItems, this);
        recyclerView1.setAdapter(adaptor);
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
        pickEntidad();
    }
    @Override
    public void OnRecipe(int priority) {

        if (priority == 20) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Solomillo.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
        if (priority == 50) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Entrecot.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
        if (priority == 100) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Hamburguesa.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    }

    private void pickEntidad(){
        final int random = new Random().nextInt(101);

        int priority1 = entidad1.getPriority();
        int priority2 = entidad2.getPriority();
        int priority3 = entidad3.getPriority();


        listItems.clear();
        if(random < priority1){

            listItems.add(entidad1);

        }else if(random < priority2){

            listItems.add(entidad2);

        }else if (random <= priority3){

            listItems.add(entidad3);

        }
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Please help I don't know what to do.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an activity not reload/refresh every time I get into it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57521189/how-to-make-an-activity-not-reload-refresh-every-time-i-get-into-it)

Answer (score 1):

you can`t prevent from reloading activity but you can retrieve last state of your activity every time onCreate() method is called by using savedInstanceState like this:

```
TextView textView;

// some transient state for the activity instance
String gameState;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // call the super class onCreate to complete the creation of activity like
    // the view hierarchy
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // recovering the instance state
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        gameState = savedInstanceState.getString(GAME_STATE_KEY);
    }

    // set the user interface layout for this activity
    // the layout file is defined in the project res/layout/main_activity.xml file
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    // initialize member TextView so we can manipulate it later
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
}

// This callback is called only when there is a saved instance that is previously saved by using
// onSaveInstanceState(). We restore some state in onCreate(), while we can optionally restore
// other state here, possibly usable after onStart() has completed.
// The savedInstanceState Bundle is same as the one used in onCreate().
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    textView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(TEXT_VIEW_KEY));
}

// invoked when the activity may be temporarily destroyed, save the instance state here
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString(GAME_STATE_KEY, gameState);
    outState.putString(TEXT_VIEW_KEY, textView.getText());

    // call superclass to save any view hierarchy
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

for more info about savedInstanceState and android lifecycles look at the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#oncreate)